# Is this a memory leak (using NSArray and NSCopying)

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I tried something out in my code to see the effect on memory utilization. I wanted to find out if the line inside the loop was leaking. Running this loop took utilization up to 100MB and it didn't go back down again. Does this indicate a memory leak? If so why? (I'm using ARC)

```
for (i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        self.accounts = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[_dal accounts] copyItems:YES];
    }
```

(accounts is an array of AccountSummary objects which implements NSCopying like this: name city state phone are all NSStrings, isLocal is BOOL)

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    AccountSummary *newAccount = [[AccountSummary allocWithZone:zone] init];

    newAccount.name = [self.name copyWithZone:zone];
    newAccount.city = [self.city copyWithZone:zone];
    newAccount.state = [self.state copyWithZone:zone];
    newAccount.phone = [self.phone copyWithZone:zone];

    newAccount.isLocal = self.isLocal;

    return newAccount;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't go back down"?

Comment: In Debug Navigator / Memory, the dashboard pointer for Memory Utilized went up to 100MB and I watched it for a few minutes after the method containing the loop ended and was still at 100MB

Comment: If you "Simulate Memory Warning" on the simulator, does it go down?

Comment: @JesseRusak, I read it as "The total memory used as shown in Instruments when I profiled didn't go down after I'd expected the objects to have been released"

Comment: Utilization steps back down sharply and automatically in the simulator even without simulating the memory warning. Same code flatlines at a high level on a real device though.

Answer (score 4):

There's no leak here that I can see. There will, however, be quite a bit of peak memory usage.

The exact behaviour of things that should *logically* release memory varies. Quite often, instead of releasing the memory it's autorelased. (With MRR, there used to be a method called `autorelease`.) When you autorelease something, it isn't really released but is instead *scheduled* for release later, when your code is finished because it's returned to the main event loop.

If part of this is being autoreleased — and my guess is that the property assignment is autoreleasing, because autorelease is "safer" than hard releasing — that memory won't be deallocated until your next autoreleasepool flush. Code on the main thread has an autoreleasepool set up by the OS itself, so each time you return to the main event loop everything that's been autoreleased gets flushed out. Here, that probably means that all 10,000,000 copies are kept in memory until you  return to the main event loop. Darn right that'll crash a real device. :)

(That's assuming you're on the main thread; if you're not, you may not even have an autorelasepool set up, which means you probably will get a leak. But I think you get warnings to console in this case, so you'd already have a hint about which way to go.)

You can reduce this peak memory usage by using `@autoreleasepool`:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) @autoreleasepool {
    self.accounts = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[_dal accounts] copyItems:YES];
}
```

What will happen now is that the memory scheduled for release later in each iteration of the loop will actually be released each iteration of the loop. That should solve your immediate problem.

That said, i can't imagine why you're doing this except to check the behaviour. And if that's the case, this is unlikely your core problem.

Assuming your core problem is a leak, with ARC you're not really looking for leaks. You're looking for circular references. That means your answer likely lies elsewhere in your code. If you're sure it's self's accounts rather than dsl's accounts that are leaking, look for self being involved in a circular loop.

Also, keep in mind that calling `copyWithZone:` on a `NSString` will probably **not** copy the string. (There's no need to copy a read-only string, as the read-only string can't be changed. Both "copies" can be the same object.) So if you're leaking just strings, they could be associated with the original objects.

Answer (score 1):

When creating lots of objects inside a loop, you should do that inside an auto release pool.

```
@autoreleasepool {
    for (i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        self.accounts = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[_dal accounts] copyItems:YES];
    }
}
```

or, more likely in the real world...

```
for (i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        self.accounts = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[_dal accounts] copyItems:YES];
    }
}
```